# location.back() routing in ionic app giving 'invalid view to enter' error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using an ionic/Angular application and was trying to route using location from @angular/common.

I am getting `'invalid views to insert'` error when I use `location.back()` functionality although it is navigating properly to the previous page.

Any ideas how I can resolve this log coming every time in my console when I am using that function?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is not prepared to handle angular routing, but it will be implemented on Ionic 4 [see here](https://www.joshmorony.com/what-to-expect-when-ionic-4-is-released/)

I would recommend you to use the `NavController` implemented by `ionic-angular`, as it is the proper way to navigate on an Ionic App at the moment.

Comment: I have been using angular routing instead of ionic routing as ionic routing was not working properly for me between modules. I am using ionic 2.

Comment: In what case it was not working correctly? And again, you should not be using angular routing...

Answer (score 0):

I run into `invalid views to insert` problem when I use Angular routing.

I solved it by adding a module for each component which will be imported in app.module.

Then adding a router in app-routing.module.